# pythonic way to replace two character in a string

Tags: python, string, replace, str-replace

I have a string ,for example `s = "-1+2-3"` I want to replace all `-` to `+` and all `+` to `-`.

what I expected is `s = +1-2+3` .So I can't just use `s.replace('-','+').replace('+','-')`,because it return `s=-1-2-3`,maybe a for loop can help. But I wonder if there is a pythonic way to do so?

> thanks for all solutions i did a simple test for all function below

```py
def a(s="-1+2-3"):
    s = re.sub('[+-]', lambda match: '-' if match[0] == '+' else '+', s)
    return s

def b(s="-1+2-3"):
    PLUS = '+'
    MINUS = '-'
    swap = {ord(PLUS): ord(MINUS), ord(MINUS): ord(PLUS)}
    s = s.translate(swap)
    return s

def c(s="-1+2-3"):
    replacements = {"+": "-", "-": "+"}

    return ''.join([replacements[i] if i in replacements.keys() else i for i in s])


def d(s="-1+2-3"):
    return s.replace('+', '\x01').replace('-', '+').replace('\x01', '-')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = timeit.timeit(a, number=100000) # a=0.20307550000000002
    b = timeit.timeit(b, number=100000) # b=0.08596850000000006
    c = timeit.timeit(c, number=100000) # c=0.12203799999999998
    d = timeit.timeit(d, number=100000) # d=0.033226100000000036
    print(f"{a=}\n{b=}\n{c=}\n{d=}\n")
```

Comment: Replace the minuses with some other unique character, say Z.    Then replace the pluses with minuses, then replace the Zs with pluses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use translate (without `ord` as pointed out by Barmar):

```
s = "-1+2-3"
s.translate(str.maketrans('-+', '+-'))
```

Output:

```
'+1-2+3'
```

Comment: You can use `str.makestrans()` instead of all the calls to `ord()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dictionary and a loop, so you can have any number of replacements in your dictionary.

```
s = "-1+2-3"
replacements = {"+":"-", "-":"+"}

s = ''.join([replacements[i] if i in replacements.keys() else i for i in s])


'+1-2+3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```py
s=s.replace('+','\x01').replace('-','+').replace('\x01','-')
```

It replaces all the '+' by an unused character, and then replaces the '-' by '+' and then replaces the "unused characters" by '-', effectivly swapping '+' and '-'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub()`.

```
import re

s = "-1+2-3"
s = re.sub('[+-]', lambda match: '-' if match[0] == '+' else '+', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many have already answered you, so I add this example for completeness using the `map()` function:

```py
def replaceSymbol(s):
    res = s;
    if '+' in s:
       res = '-'
    elif '-' in s:
        res = '+'
    return res
        
''.join(map(replaceSymbol, "-1+2-3"))
```

Output:

```
+1-2+3
```